# Updating a column if the validating column value is NULL in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am new to postgres and trying to update the columns where the status is either null or new.
The below query is validating for NEW but not for empty string/null value. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
update test_table c 
set FLAG = -1, err_det='Incorrect entry' 
where FName is not null and Status in ('NEW','')
```

This query is being used inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you if your default value is NULL

```
update test_table c set FLAG = -1, err_det='Incorrect entry' where FName is not null and  (Status IS NULL OR Status='NEW');
```

Considering change  `Status in ('NEW','')` to `(Status IS NULL OR Status='NEW')`

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question I was unsure if you wanted to update just `NULL` and the `'NEW'` value or 'empty string/null value' as you mentioned.

Below will work for the values `NULL`/`'NEW'`/ and 'empty string'.

```
UPDATE test_table c 
SET FLAG = -1, err_det='Incorrect entry' 
WHERE FName is NOT NULL AND  
(Status IS NULL OR Status='NEW' OR Status='')
```

Below just `NULL` and `'NEW'`.

```
UPDATE test_table c 
SET FLAG = -1, err_det='Incorrect entry' 
WHERE FName IS NOT NULL AND  
(Status IS NULL OR Status='NEW')
```